# Multi-level ordered list with prefix in different parts of the text

Tags: xetex, lists, pandoc

I'm writing a document with a list of items that must be ordered.

The result should be something like this:

```
Title 1
R1. Requirement 1
  R1.1 Requirement 1.1
R2. Item 2
  R2.1 Requirement 2.1
    R2.1.1 Requirement 2.1.1

Title 2
R3. Requirement 3
  R3.1 Requirement 3.1
```

I'm trying to use `Pandoc` (From `Markdown` to `Latex`) but if it's not possible, it is not a problem to ditch Markdown.

I'm a little lost on how to look for this on the Internet and I'm a `Latex` newbie so any help is welcome :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal example code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you're after?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Renum}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[Renum, 1]{label = R\arabic*., wide=0pt}
\setlist*[Renum,2]{label*=\arabic*., wide=1.5em}
\setlist*[Renum,3]{label*=\arabic*.,wide=3em}

\begin{document}

\section{Title 1}
    \begin{Renum}
        \item Requirement 1
\begin{Renum}
        \item Requirement 1.1
\end{Renum}
\item Item 2
\begin{Renum}
        \item Requirement 2.1
\begin{Renum}
        \item Requirement 2.1.1
\end{Renum}
\end{Renum}
\end{Renum}

\section{Title2}
    \begin{Renum}[resume*]
        \item Requirement 3
\begin{Renum}
        \item Requirement3.1

\end{Renum}
\end{Renum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I knew about the resume package but I had no idea about the \setlist

Comment: One learns a lot of useful things reading the documentations… B.t.w., `resume` is not a package – only a key defined by `enumitem`, which also has, for more complex situations, the `series` key.